# How to make a new Activity visible in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

This may seem trivial but I have no idea how and the lack of terminlogy in my google searches are turning up nothing. I already have a single main activity which looks like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DroidPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.all_songs:
                Toast.makeText(DroidPlayerActivity.this, "Pressed All Songs TextView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new AllSongsActivity();//nothing shows up
                break;
            case R.id.recently_added:
                Toast.makeText(DroidPlayerActivity.this, "Pressed Recently Added TextView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            ...
        }

    }
}
```

in my `onClick(View v)` method I check which `TextView` was pressed and initiate a new instance of the `AllSongsActivity`, however, nothing shows up (activity is not visible still shows my main activity). 
The `AllSongsActivity` class is just a simple *blank* `Activity` for now:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class AllSongsActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_songs);
    }

}
```

So to clarify how do I make the `AllSongsActivity` visible taking it that I have the `DroidPlayerActivity` already running (its the main).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not create instances of activities yourself. Instead, you call `startActivity()` to start an activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, AllSongsActivity.class));
```

Comment: +1 thank you for the answer but when I do this my application forces close when I click the TextView associated with `startActivity(new Intent(this, AllSongsActivity.class));`

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: will do thanks thats for another question then :) (I'll accept when minutes are up)

Answer (score 1):

To call a new Activity from the current one, you can't just instantiate that Activity's class. You must use an [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

something like this:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Also you shoul check up the Android official docs, especially the API Guide, it sheds tons of light on common issues like this one:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Please go over documentation about Intents. Intents is used for start another activity in android.

For ex,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AllSongsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); // This will start AllSongsActivity activity
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to send an Intent to the Activity you want to start like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AllSongsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Edit: already answered!

Comment: +1 thank you for the answer but when I do this my application stops unexpectedly

Comment: Can you report the Eclipse log of the error? Did you declare the AllSongsActivity in your application manifest? Maybe this is what you're missing!

Comment: Yes I found out that I didnt decalre it in the manifest :) thank you. Previously +1

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DroidPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.all_songs:
                Toast.makeText(DroidPlayerActivity.this, "Pressed All Songs TextView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ---- show next activity ----
                Intent intent = new Intent(DroidPlayerActivity.this, AllSongsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.recently_added:
                Toast.makeText(DroidPlayerActivity.this, "Pressed Recently Added TextView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            ...
        }

    }
}
```